# How to edit files in text editor and not terminal when using nano command?

Tags: editors, nano

So when I use nano  it opens a little interface to edit the file. However, is there a way to open the file with text editor?, as that is much easier to edit, navigate and save.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/986977/how-to-edit-files-in-text-editor-and-not-terminal-when-using-nano-command

Comment: Firstly `nano` is a text editor as is `vim`. Secondly, *easy* is subjective. It doesn't get much easier than `nano` or `vim`.

Comment: It's much harder to navigate - e.g. you can't change position with your mouse, you have to use arrows etc. And to save the file it takes 3 commands as opposed to simply `command + S`

Comment: If your criteria for easy is fewer key-strokes or mouse support then why not `vim`?: `ZZ` or `:x` (save and quit) `:set mouse=a` ([all mouse features](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'mouse')).

Comment: Or [`emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) if you are looking for a more elegant GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Nano Is a text editor. Now I must admit that I dislike it And the first thing I do is uninstall it and install my prefered editor, but it is an editor capable of doing all basic editing tasks.
2. if you type nano chances are you will start nano. If you do not want to run nano, don't type nano.
3. If you did not type nano, but it started anyway for example `sudoedit`, `visudo`, etc. either set the EDITOR or VISUAL environment variable to point to the editor of your choice (remember that you may need the editor to not background itself or it will cause problems with the wrappers). Also if you are using a debian derived distro sensible-editor and alternatives allow further configuration.
4. If you did not type nano and You are still getting nano In spite of the above you can rename nano to something like nano.real and make a symbolic link from nano to the editor of your choice (as long as your editor does not automatically background itself, a wrapper script may help).